# How do I compile ASIS for GNAT on 7.4?

Tags: ada, asis

I've downloaded the code from the repository [here](https://github.com/simonjwright/ASIS/tree/master), and have run the `make` command after reading the README file (which is quite long, so I probably missed some things in it).

I'm getting a build error, the source of which is not altogether clear. The `make` process terminates in the following:

```
compilation of asis-data_decomposition-set_get.adb failed
compilation of asis-text.adb failed
compilation of a4g-contt-dp.adb failed

gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
```

See [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/XQgJf73h) for the full output of `make`. What do I need to do to build ASIS (the end goal of which is to enable me to run the [AdaControl](https://sourceforge.net/p/adacontrol/code/ci/master/tree/) build process)?

Answer (score 3):

The most important comment in the README (I hope it is there) is that you have to use matching versions of GNAT and ASIS4GNAT, for anything to work.

Your compiler seems to be GNAT Pro 2.3.2, while the latest commit in the ASIS repository you use seems to be for GNAT GPL 2017.  They are definitely not matching versions, so it shouldn't work.

You should find/download ASIS4GNAT for GNAT Pro 2.3.2 and build that. - Or switch compilers to GNAT GPL 2017.

Comment: You might be interested in [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52085810/unable-to-compile-adacontrol-unknown-project-file-asis) also... not sure what to do here.

Comment: If you are proposing to use GNAT Pro 7.4, then there’s a reasonable chance that ASIS from GNAT CE 2018 can be wrangled to work with it. You’ll find I’ve updated my ASIS repo (master branch, at the moment, should really call it upstream) with that ASIS. BUT, I for one am still baffled as to what actual version of the compiler you’re using. I don’t care about the GPS version or the gprbuild version, and I don’t recognise "6.4.2" or "7.4.2".

Answer (score 1):

I see I need to provide something in [my ASIS repo](https://github.com/simonjwright/ASIS/tree/master) to make this clearer.

The purpose of that repo is to make public changes needed to the GPL (now CE) releases of ASIS to run with FSF GCC.

If you can switch compilers to GNAT GPL 2017, you can download the matching ASIS source from [AdaCore](https://www.adacore.com/download) (look for 'Sources'). Better, if you can switch to GNAT CE 2018, you’ll find it comes with ASIS already.

If you are fixed on the GNAT Pro compiler you seem to be using, you could try downloading the community (GPL) ASIS sources from as near a date as possible (2016?).

Comment: It occurs to me that you could build AdaControl with GNAT CE 2018 and then just use it - it won’t care what compiler you’re going to use to build _your_ application.

Comment: We're using Gnat 6.4.2 (gprbuild v 1.5.2), but we also have our project lined up to move to Gnat 7.4.2 which is the 2.3.2 version. I am told that it would be difficult to move beyond this due to some linking with older C-libraries that no longer works in the newer versions, but I have not verified that myself and do not know the nature of those issues.

Comment: So given that info, which one do I download from Adacore? They are numbered by year so it's not clear to me which one to pull.

Comment: I said "It occurs to me that you could build AdaControl with GNAT CE 2018 and then just use it - it won’t care what compiler you’re going to use to build your application" - but of course that’s rubbish, AdaControl needs to compile your sources with the compiler that was used to build AdaControl. You could install CE 2018 purely for use with AdaControl, and continue to build your application with the compilers you mention.

Comment: If you say `gnatls -v` you should get a report of the compiler version, including the date. I’d start from that.

Comment: So, you're saying we could hypothetically run AdaControl under CE 2018, then go back and recompile under 7.4? Does it matter if our project won't compile under 2018? I thought everything needed to be at 7.4 - the issue is that I can't find the 7.4 version of ASIS... haven't even gotten to the point where I *can* compile AdaControl.

Comment: By the way, I did download CE 2017 version, and was able to compile the code in your repo without difficulty. However, trying to compile `adacontrol-code` yields `build.gpr:1:06: unknown project file: "asis"` and fails. Separate question, or something related?

Comment: @theMayer Compile?  Or link?  If the challenge is just about linking, then you don't have a problem.  If it can't compile with CE 2018, then there's no point in experimenting.

Comment: If your project won’t compile under CE 2018 then you can’t do what I suggested (which, by the way, isn’t far off what you’d do if you had an embedded target that you had to cross-compile for, and wanted to run desktop tests with suitable harnesses).

Comment: Please, run `gcc -v` and tell us exactly what the end of the output is. I don’t believe your compiler could be 2.3.2 (The GNAT Pro I last used 7 years ago was at 3.16a1, and we’d been using it for several years by then). For info, GNAT CE 2018 for macOS says `gcc version 7.3.1 20180524 (for GNAT Community 2018 20180523) (GCC) `.