# Unable to compile AdaControl: unknown project file: "asis"

Tags: ada

I downloaded the source for [AdaControl](http://www.adalog.fr/en/adacontrol.html) from the [SourceForge Repo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adacontrol/).  Using GNAT 2017 CE, I get the following error on `make`:

```
$ make build
gprbuild build.gpr adactl  -cargs  -bargs  -largs 
build.gpr:1:06: unknown project file: "asis"
gprbuild: "build.gpr" processing failed
make: *** [adactl] Error 4
```

The [instructions](http://www.adalog.fr/compo/adacontrol_ug.html) make it sound like this is all I need to do, and offer no troubleshooting suggestions:

> Go to the root directory of the distribution and type:
>
> make build make install

As [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066601/how-do-i-compile-asis-for-gnat-on-7-4/52076003?noredirect=1#comment91121031_52076003) notes, I have managed to get ASIS to build, though it also comes packaged with GNAT 2017 CE.

Answer (score 2):

That message means that ASIS4GNAT isn't installed in a place where `gprbuild` (and the rest of your GCC/Ada tool-chain) can find it.

You can use the command `gnatls -v` to get an idea about where your GCC/Ada tool-chain expects project files to be located.

Compare that to where you actually installed ASIS4GNAT, and you may be closer to a solution.

Comment: So, this makes sense in principle... Gnat is located in $GNAT_HOME, `/opt/share/gnat`, and I believe ASIS is in `/opt/share/gnat/include/asis` --- the include folder came with the install, so how do I correct it to know where to look?

Comment: I’d expect `asis.gpr` to have been installed in `/opt/share/gnat/share/gpr` (judging by where CE 2018 has it), which is a standard place. Assuming, that is, that `gcc` is in `/opt/share/gnat/bin`, i.e. that `$prefix` is `/opt/share/gnat`.